# how to create a dynamic webpage using node js?

Tags: node.js

I am new to node js. i am trying to learn node js. My question is how can we create dynamic webpages using node js?

PHP

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php .......... ?>
</body>
```

Like in php we can do this way. How can we do in node js.

Comment: look into this package https://expressjs.com/

Comment: Also take a look at the [Express application generator](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html) - maybe a good point to start at.

Comment: This might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54363688/nodejs-dynamically-create-html-from-an-object/63807848#63807848

Answer (score 7):

First off you would start by installing the nodejs framework expressJS

```
sudo npm install express
```

For instance, let's say you want to create a form.

```
<html>
<body>
<head>
This is a simple form
</head>
<body>
<form action="/" method="POST">
<label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
<input name="firstName">
<br>
<label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
<input name="lastName">
<br>
<button type="submit">send</button>
```

This what the server side part would look like

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false});

// Set EJS View Engine**
app.set('view engine','ejs');
// Set HTML engine**
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
//set directory
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
//static folder
app.use(express.static('staticfolder'));


app.get('/form', function(req, res) {
    //open form.html from the views directory
    res.render('form');
});

app.post('/', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
    //retrieve first and lastname
    var firstName = req.body.firstName;
    var lastName = req.body.lastName;
    //open submitted.html after the user has submitted the form
    res.render('submitted', {output: req.body.firstName});
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Page that will be displayed when user submits the form. It is called submitted.html in this case

```
<html>
<body>

<p> you have submitted the form </p>
<!--firstname entered by user-->
<p> your first name is <%= output %></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a template to dynamically change its content.
Step 1: Create a server with Express Node.JS Framework.
Step 2: Use EJS(Embedded JavaScript)  to create a template.
Follow the instructions bellow:
https://shockoe.com/ideas/development/creating-dynamic-web-pages-ejs/